# free-jqgrid populate drop down in subgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am having a devil of a time populating a drop down list in a sub-grid. I am using free-jqgrid 4.15.5. I have no issues when populating a drop down in the main grid but it appears that I am having ID issues when trying to get a simular drop down in the subgrid ( grid as a subgrid option) dows anyone know a reference or how to populate the drop down correctly?

my current test function for the drop down is:

```
function popUsersT() {

alert("subgrid id : " + window.subgrid_id + "\nfound : " + $("#" + subgrid_id).length + "\nrow id : " + window.row_id + "\nfound(row) : " + $("#" + window.row_id).length + "\ndropdown found : " + $("select", "#" + window.row_id).length + "\nsg_tableID: " + $("#" + sg_tableID).html);
var current = $("#" + subgrid_id).jqGrid('getRowData', $("#" + window.subgrid_table_id )[0].p.selrow).TaskValidator;
alert(current);

$.ajax({
    url: "/Tasks/getUserList",
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'Get',
    async: false,
    success: function (users) {
        $("#Task").html("");
        $("#Proxy").html("");
        $.each(users, function (i, user) {
            $("#Task").append(
                $('<option></option>').val(user.name).html(user.DisplayName)
            );
            $("#Proxy").append(
                $('<option></option>').val(user.name).html(user.DisplayName)
            );
        });
        $("#Task").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#Proxy").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#Task").val(current);
        $("#Proxy").val(current);
    }
});
```

}

part of my subgrid is:

```
subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
        var sg_tableID = subgrid_id + "_t";
        window.subgrid_id = sg_tableID;
        window.row_id = row_id;
        window.subgrid_table_id = sg_tableID;
        //alert(subgrid_id);
        //alert(row_id);
        var pager_id = "p_" + sg_tableID;
        $("#" + subgrid_id).html("<table id='" + sg_tableID + "' class='scroll'></table><div id='" + pager_id + "' class='scroll'></div>");
        jQuery("#" + sg_tableID).jqGrid({
            url: "/Home/GetTaskSubList/" + row_id,
```

I keep playing with the Id values to try to get away from the errors of:
Error: 'subgrid_table_id' is undefined 
Error: 'sg_tableID' is undefined

I am sure i am getting lost in trying to make this work, and was hoping this was something easy i am over looking.

thank you for your help

Comment: Where (in which function: `popUsersT` or other, in which line of the function) you get the error? It's unclear which relation has the code of `popUsersT` function to the code of `subGridRowExpanded`. Moreover, you set some properties on `windows` object inside of `subGridRowExpanded`: `subgrid_id`, `row_id` and `subgrid_table_id` (with *the same* value as `subgrid_id`). Inside of `popUsersT` you use in some places `window.subgrid_id` in other `window.subgrid_table_id` and sometimes `subgrid_id` **without `window.` prefix**. It looks wrong.

Comment: I was able to figure this out. `code` subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
            var sg_tableID = subgrid_id + "_t";
            window.subgrid_id = sg_tableID;
            window.row_id = row_id;
            window.subgrid_table_id = sg_tableID; and then in my I referenced `code`currentOwner = $("#" + subgrid_id).jqGrid('getRowData', $("#" + window.subgrid_table_id)[0].p.selrow).Task; to get it working Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end iw as able to get it workign by setting the values:

```
subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
        var sg_tableID = subgrid_id + "_t";
        window.subgrid_id = sg_tableID;
        window.row_id = row_id;
        window.subgrid_table_id = sg_tableID;
```

and then referencing the values in the function by:

```
var currentOwner = $("#" + subgrid_id).jqGrid('getRowData', $("#" + window.subgrid_table_id)[0].p.selrow).Task;
```

I am not sure i fully understand the why but it does seem to work as needed. thank you